# How to use the "as of" phrase correctly

Tags: grammar

I've found the following sentence in an article written in 2008. 
"As of 2000, the United States has dramatically increased the penalties for trafficking offenses."
With regard to the tense, isn't it correct to say, "...the United States had..."?

Comment: It depends on whether the meaning is "at that time" or "from that time and ongoing to the present".

Comment: I thought that "as of 2000" meant "up until 2000".

Comment: No, it means that at that point in time the condition was was true.  The expression does not inherently imply whether the condition was true before that point or remained true after that point (or not).

Comment: The article was written in 2008 and the event in 2000 was past. Can we still use "has" instead of "had"?

Comment: It depends on whether the condition is continuing or not.  If the penalties are still increased at the time of writing (and essentially unchanged from 2000), and if later developments are not about to be discussed, then "has" is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

"As of", according to *Merriam-Webster,* [means](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20of) "on, at, from—used to indicate a time or date at which something begins or ends."

> So the text could be saying that **from** 2000, the United States has
>   dramatically increased the penalties for trafficking offenses.

That would explain why they used "has" instead of "had".